# get value from particular index in java?

Tags: arrays

in one big grid array(like 500 rows,500 columns), i want to get the value by using index as (150th row,200th column).The condition is , i should not us one dimensional array,2 dimensional,3 dimensional for retrieving that values.
i have no idea in hashmap?my colleague told to get the values from hashmap ?but i dont know
how to pass the index and get the value?plz help me anyone??????

Comment: Please accept answers to your previous questions. Also, please reword your question. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completly understand your sentence, but thing is, you can use a single index to access the positions using something like an hashmap, if you make sure the keys you use for placing the values are unique.

For the hashmap example you mention, you just have to imagine of putting all the elements of your matrix (grid) in a line, meaning that for position i, j,   in a single index x, it would be:

```
 index x = (max_line_length*(i-1))+j
```

where `max_line_length = your_matrix.length`

Comment: sorry if u dint understand my question????what am i asking know, in 2 dimensional array if we pass the index as row,column (example a[150][200]) ,we will get the value of it.like tat can I do in hashmap  row and column as key?

Comment: You can do it in a hashmap if you use both indexes in a combined way, like I suggested, yes.

Comment: how to put the values into hashmap using index?for that we need key know?here key as row and column(example 150row,200th column).how to use index as key whatever u suggested?it will be same only na.sorry for asking again and again?can u brief me littlebit wat u suggested?

Comment: For the conversion, you need to do a for inside a for, passing by each element of your array, and for each position, calculate x and add the  array[i][j] element to the hashmap, with the x key you calculated based on that same i and j. After the for loop ends, you will have all the array elements in the hashmap, with a key that you can relate with the initial i and j.